# In what way was the carnal Jesus the sanctuary of God?

Tags: jesus

> Saying, Let us alone; what have we to do with thee, thou Jesus of Nazareth? art thou come to destroy us? I know thee who thou art, the Holy One of God. Mark 1:24 KJV

Comment: The adjective "Holy" (HAGIOS) means ANYTHING that belongs to God. Not just sanctuaries.

Comment: The syntactic construction in the genitive case always refers to Sanctuary (LXX).  Lev. 21:23; 1 Chr. 22:19; Ps. Sol. 8:11 and  Dan. 9:20;

Comment: It is incorrect (on every possible level) to refer to the 'carnal' Jesus. The correct adjective is the 'incarnate' but then one must specify _Whom_ is incarnate, which is a matter of the Son of God. Jesus of Nazareth was never 'carnal'.

Answer (score 1):

The pertinent word here is Ἅγιος (hargios) which can be either an adjective, as in Mark 1:24, or a noun, in which case it would be translated, "holy thing" or "saint".

The primary meaning of the word is "dedicated in service to God" (BDAG) and thgus it is used to describe various such thing dedicated in service to God such as:

**Objects**

- Jerusalem = the Holy City, Matt 4:5, 27:54, Rev 11:2, 21:2, etc
- The place where Moses stood at the burning bush, holy ground, Acts 7:33
- The holy mountain of transfiguration, 2 Peter 1:18
- The desert tabernacle or sanctuary, Heb 9:2
- The holy covenant, Luke 1:72
- The holy scriptures, Rom 1:2
- The holy commandment, 2 Peter 2:21

**People**

- The lives of Christians, 2 Tim 1:9
- The holy priesthood or believers, 1 Peter 2:5
- The holy nation of Christians, 1 Peter 2:9
- Holy prophets, Luke 1:70, Acts 3:21, 2 Peter 3:2
- John the Baptist, Mark 6:20
- Apostles, Eph 3:5
- Holy women, 1 Peter 3:5
- Firstborn of a woman, Luke 2:23
- Members of the church, Col 1:26, Heb 3:1, Eph 1:4, 5:27.
- children of church members, 1 Cor 7:14
- Patriarchs, Rom 11:16

**Christ and other heavenly beings**

- angels, Mark 8:38, Luke 9:26, Acts 10:22, Rev 14:10
- Christ, Mark 1:24, Acts 4:27, 30, Luke 1:35
- God, John 17:11, 1 Peter 1:16b, Rev 4:8, 6:10, Luke 1:49
- The Holy Spirit - many times

The cognate noun is translated "saints" (many times) describing church members as holy people.

The central matter here is simple - God's people are called to be holy because Christ Jesus, God and the Holy Spirit are holy:

- Lev 20:26 - You are to **be holy** to Me because I, the LORD, am holy, and I have set you apart from the nations to be My own.
- Lev 21:6 - They must **be holy** to their God and not profane the name of their God. Because they present to the LORD the offerings made by fire, the food of their God, they must be holy.
- Lev 19:2 - “Speak to the whole congregation of Israel and tell them: **Be holy because I, the LORD your God, am holy**.
- Lev 11:44 - For I am the LORD your God; consecrate yourselves, therefore, and **be holy, because I am holy**. You must not defile yourselves by any creature that crawls along the ground.
- Lev 11:45 - For I am the LORD, who brought you up out of the land of Egypt so that I would be your God; therefore **be holy, because I am holy**.
- 1 Peter 1:15 - But just as He who called you is holy, so **be holy** in all you do,
- 1 Peter 1:16 - because it has been written: "You shall **be holy, because I am holy**." (quoting the above!)
- 1 Cor 1:2 - To the church of God in Corinth, to those **sanctified** in Christ Jesus and **called to be holy**, together with all those everywhere who call on the name of our Lord Jesus Christ, their Lord and ours:
- Rom 1:7 - To all in Rome who are loved by God and **called to be his holy people**: Grace and peace to you from God our Father and from the Lord Jesus Christ.
- 2 Tim 1:9 - He has saved us and called us to a **holy calling**, not because of our works, but by His own purpose and by the grace He granted us in Christ Jesus before time began.

Jesus is described as Holy (see above list), therefore, we must be holy, ie, dedicated in service to God alone.